# How to elevate a drop down list, because some of its items are hidden by the keyboard?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I tried to show the complete drop down list, but the keyboard hides some of its items, like this..

[image]

(The right most drop down list button)

The third item '!!!' is hidden and can only be shown if I choose the '!!' item, then click the drop down list again. And this is how the drop down list looks like if not clicked..

[image]

I tried to modify my code using `Transform.trnaslate(...)` as in the next code sample

```
Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(0, -20),
      child: DropdownButton(
        items: ..., // items shown in the list
        onChanged: (value) {
         ...
        }
      ...
      ))
```

and this is what I've got

[image]

How can I unhide the hidden items?

Comment: Consider adding a minimal reproducible example. This will help other users see the issue themselves. Here is an example https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

Answer (score 0):

Simply Wrap Your Scaffold Body With The List View.

It Only Occurs Because He is not Getting the Proper Space